# Unable to fill in text in PDF form

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I am trying to fill in a PDF form-- but for some reason I am unable to fill in any text? When I try to even Paste some text, even that is not allowed.

For reference, I have uploaded the form here on my Skydrive-> 
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=2D1BE48F6B626811!146953&authkey=!AGxCyuYBsL35sZo

How do I fill in the various fields in that PDF Form? Why am I not able to fill it in?

For reference Adobe Reader 11.

Comment: @pnuts- I need it for change of name.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1 if you select the 'Incorporating a new company' radio button then the form fields will be enabled so that you can fill them out. There is a lot of JavaScript validation used in these form fields so you will need to fill out all of the required form fields in the correct order.

In addition, if you go to Document Properties > Security (Ctrl+D) for this PDF you will see that it has a note: * This PDF form restricts some operations.

Changing the document is not permitted with the exception of filling out the form fields.

This PDF has not been secured in the traditional sense (i.e. with a password) but rather it has been generated in a program such as Adobe LiveCycle with a special digital signature that prevents certain behavior, unlocks hidden functionality in Adobe Reader and prevents this PDF from being opened in non-Adobe applications.